# whats the syntax for facebook graph api post

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

im using facebook javascript sdk for facebook graph api.
here is my syntax that im using when the user perform login to system -

```
FB.api("/me/photos?access_token="+response.authResponse.accessToken, "POST", 
{ "source": "http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" }
                , { scope: 'email,user_likes,publish_actions' });
```

i want that when the user enter the site this picture will be posted in his time line.

what am i doing wrong ?

in the console i can get "reading" actions - so the connection is fine and its just a syntax error for the post method...

**UPDATE:**

its not an authentication problem cause this code is working for me:

```
 FB.login(function () {
            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: 'Hello, world!' });
        }, { scope: 'publish_actions' });
```

Comment: Is the user authenticating? He/she needs to explicitly allow your app to post content.

Comment: You should try and keep you code consistent so either use strings or not for your object keys ( `"source"` and `scope` ). Other than that your code looks fine. Are you sure the syntax error is not on a previous line?

Comment: hi i've updated the question - its not an authentication problem... the message code is working - just uploading the image isn't :(

Comment: _“i want that when the user enter the site this picture will be posted in his time line”_ – automated posting of content that the user did not create actively is against Platform Policies. You should never publish anything just because the user logged in to your site, but only if the actively chose that they want to post something.

Answer (score 0):

it was just a syntax error - 
 here is the right code:

```
FB.login(function () {
            FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', { "url": "http://carpaper.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/-image.jpg" });
        }, { scope: 'publish_actions' });
```

:)